# Json array contains particular jsonobject

Tags: android

I am storing my values in a json array. Now i need to check that whether the array `contains only ( silk,jute,cotton)`. If so I donot want to proceed. But if my array contains all items except this I need to proceed. What is the condition to be checked for that. Can anyone please help

```
    JSONObject itemJson = new JSONObject();
    itemJson.put("IsCustom", false);
    itemJson.put("Quantity", item.getQuantity());
    orderItems.put(itemJson);
```

Appreciate if you could help, thanks in advance.

```
1) if array contains -{"silk,quantity"} ->proceed
 2) if array contains -{"silk"} -> block
 3) if array contains -{"silk,false"} ->proceed
 4) ) if array contains -{"cotton"} -> block
```

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You may check by using below code

```
if ((array.has("silk")) || (array.has("jute")) || (array.has("cotton"))) {
  // do what you like
  } else {
     // code
  }
```